# Lower bound of embedding dimension for finite CW-Complex of dimension $d$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Consider a finite CW-Complex $C$ of dimension $d$. Let $n$ be the smallest integer such that the complex embeds in $\mathbb{R}^n$. From Whitney it follows that $n \leq 2d$. How would you bound the embedding dimension of $C^k$? Is it possible to get a lower bound given the embedding dimension of $C$. What properties of $C$ could be used to give bounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For non-manifolds, it is not true that $n\leq 2d$.  For example, a graph is a $1$-dimensional CW complex, and non-planar graphs are those for which the embedding into $\mathbb{R}^2$ fails.  For smooth manifolds, the Whitney embedding theorem is that $n\leq 2d$.  I hadn't heard of this until Mike Miller suggested looking into it, but since a finite $d$-dimensional CW complex is a compact metric separable space of inductive dimension $d$, the Menger-Nöbeling theorem implies it can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2d+1}$.

There are lower bounds on $n$ one can get from Stiefel-Whitney classes for smooth manifolds.  See Milnor-Stasheff,  "Characteristic Classes."

Invariance of domain implies that $d\leq n$.

There is an obstruction by van Kampen that may show that $C$ cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$.  For $d\geq 3$, Wu and Shapiro proved the obstruction is zero if and only if $n\leq 2d$.  For $d=1$, Sarkaria (and Tutte) showed the obstruction is zero if and only if the graph is planar (i.e., $n\leq 2$).  Freedman-Krushkal-Teichner showed there is a $2$-complex that does not embed in $\mathbb{R}^4$ even though its van Kampen obstruction is zero. https://math.berkeley.edu/~teichner/Papers/vanKampen.pdf

Comment: Thank you. What about Cartesian Products? Can you bound the embedding dimension then? Is the lower bound just the product?

Comment: Is it clear that $n \leq 2d+1$? This is the case for simplicial complexes and hence for regular CW complexes. I didn't immediately see an argument for a general CW complex.

Comment: @MikeMiller Apparently it follows from the Menger-Nöbeling theorem since a finite $d$-dimensional CW complex is a compact metric separable space of inductive dimension $d$ (and the Nöbeling-Pontryagin theorem is that they can be embedded at all).

Comment: Ah, I'd heard of that before but *totally* forgotten it existed. Thanks for the reminder. (This addition might improve your already quite good answer.)

Comment: @Halbort The sum of the minimal embedding dimensions is an upper bound for the Cartesian product's minimal embedding dimension, but I'm not sure if there's a general lower bound other than the maximum of the two dimensions.  An interesting example is that $\prod_{i=1}^m S^{n_i}$ can be embedded in dimension $1+\sum_{i=1}^m n_i$ (which should be the best possible), where the naive upper bound gives $\sum_{i=1}^m(1+n_i)=m+\sum_{i=1}^mn_i$.

Comment: @Halbort Another example is a torus (embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^3$) and the unit interval (embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^1$).  Their Cartesian product is embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  This is at least a little evidence for $\max\{d_1,d_2\}$ being the best general lower bound.

Comment: But isn't the topological dimension of a torus 2 but the embedding definition 3.